# Incomplete Json is generated APIS is not coming. Can somebody check

Tags: json, swagger

Using this code:

```
@Path("/dbresource")
@Api(value = "Available_Connections", description = "List of available DB connections to generate the report", position = 1)
public class DbConnectionResource {

    private static final Logger log = Logger
            .getLogger(DbConnectionResource.class);
    public ConnectionProperties m_objConnProperties = new ConnectionProperties();
    private List<ConnectionProperties> m_listOfTempProperties = new ArrayList<ConnectionProperties>();
    private List<String> m_dbResources = new ArrayList();
    private JDBCConnectionFactory m_objConnFactory = new JDBCConnectionFactory();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(
            value = "Available connection details.",
            notes = "List all Possible connections with the default one",
            position = 1,
            httpMethod = "GET",
            produces = "application/json"
            )
    @ApiResponses( value={
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully retrieved."),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unable to generate Report due to incorrect mapping between DB and template")
    })
    private Response getAvailableDBResources() {
        try {

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(JDBCConnectionFactory.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            m_objConnFactory = (JDBCConnectionFactory) jaxbUnmarshaller
                    .unmarshal(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                            "JdbcConnections.xml"));
            m_listOfTempProperties = m_objConnFactory.getConnections()
                    .getConnection();
            System.out.println(m_listOfTempProperties.size());
            for (ConnectionProperties cpt : m_listOfTempProperties) {
                m_dbResources.add(cpt.getConnectionname());
                System.out.println("all conn"+cpt.getConnectionname());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("inside jaxb exp");
            log.debug("inside exception jaxb " + e.getMessage(), e);
            return Response.status(401).build();
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gson.toJson(m_dbResources);
        return Response.ok(gson).build();

    }
}
```

I get the following output from swagger-core:

```
{
  "apiVersion" : "1.1",
  "swaggerVersion" : "1.2",
  "basePath" : "http://localhost:8090/report-service",
  "resourcePath" : "/Avalable_Connections"
}
```

Where is the documentation of my resources?

Comment: Sorry I can't participate in your problem but I can't help but noticing the "swagger" word in the browser tab ; how come ? where does this "swagger" comes from?!

Comment: please provide more structured information on what you're doing, what you expect to see and what you're actually seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using an older version of swagger-core that produces Swagger 1.2 definitions. In that case, the output is actually fine.

You'll find the resource documentation under `/api-docs/Avalable_Connections`. That's just the structure of Swagger 1.2.

If you upgrade to the latest swagger-core, you'll get Swagger 2.0 and the whole definition in a single file.

Comment: I corrected it by converting private method to public .. anyways thanks for your response..